# Execute postInstall externally

Tags: apex, postinstall

Is it possible to execute Post install script (which implements installHandler) again after the package is already installed using execute anonymous window?

Background: after sandbox refresh, postinstall script needs to be executed in turn to reset all the custom settings

Answer (score 1):

You can call `new MyInstallHandler().onInstall(null);` to call the method, just as you could any other method, but if you need any version data in the method, then your method won't execute correctly (because the value would be null). Note that this call would execute as yourself, rather than the usual "ghost" install handler user.

Comment: Thanks @sfdxfox. That worked on my developer org where I have my code. But it didn't work where I have installed the managed package (even with namespace added to the code)

Comment: @SandeepPatwardhan if not global, the method is inaccessible to subscribers. Make the clay global, or provide a Visualforce, Aura, or LWC that can call it to the package.